# ForeAch deja de listar datos de DB despues del septimo registro

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

Estoy trabajando en Java JSP con el patrón mvc usando servlet, en la hoja de html tengo  inputs y 2 select option que cargan los datos de la base de datos con forEach de la libreria jstl.
Así de esta manera como ven mi código todo funciona normal no importa cuantas veces oprima el botón agregar siempre muestra nuevamente la pagina, pero si ingreso otro div con 1 input o simplemente un espacio de 5 saltos de linea
y oprimo el boton agregar todo desaparece.
No entiendo porque solo estoy agregando mas etiquetas de html. Pero al parecer el error es por los forEach si los quito no pasa ese error y puedo agregar muchas mas etiquetas de html.
Aparte de este en otra pagina tengo un error similar es que cargo 6 datos de la base de datos igualmente con el forEach carga 6 datos y todo funciona normal y si carga 7 datos de la db y oprimo un boton se me desaparece lo que muestran los forEach.
Estoy trabajando con esta libreria y los jstl 1.2.1

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
Quien me pueda indicar el porque agradezco mucho. Gracias

```
<form action="Controlador?menu=Empleado" method="POST">
 <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                            <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="area" >
                                                <option selected>Areas</option>
                                                <c:forEach var="areas" items="${areas}">
                                                    <option  value="${areas.getId()}" > ${areas.getArea()} </option>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <select class="browser-default custom-select"  name="rol">
                                                <option selected>Roles</option>
                                                <c:forEach var="rol" items="${roles}">
                                                    <option  value="${rol.getId()}" > ${rol.getRol()} </option>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div> ${info.getMsjinfo()} </div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary" >
                                </form>
```

El case "Listar" es quien me llama los datos de la base de datos para mostrar las opciones en los select option de html.

En mi controlador servlet tengo donde recibo los datos y doy las instrucciones.
Antes de finalizar el if tengo la instrucción request, donde indica que despues de cumplir una condicion dentro de los case debe seguir redirigiendo a la pagina Empleado.jsp

```
if (menu.equals("Empleado")) {
            switch (accion) {
                case "Listar"://----> Listar roles y areas
                    List listrol = daorol.listar(); // Lista = el metodo listar de la clase CRolesDAO
                    request.setAttribute("roles", listrol); // Al atributo que se recibe en el html recibe el atributo "roles" para listar los roles
                    List listarea = daoarea.listar();
                    request.setAttribute("areas", listarea);
                    break;
                case "Agregar":
                    try {
                        // Se reciben los campos de texto
                        String nombres = request.getParameter("txtnombres");
                        String apellidos = request.getParameter("txtapellidos");
                        String telefono = request.getParameter("txttelefono");
                        String correo = request.getParameter("txtcorreo");
                        String clave = request.getParameter("txtclave");
                        String clave2 = request.getParameter("txtclave2");
                        int area = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("area"));
                        int rol = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rol"));

                        if (clave == clave2) {
                            us.setNombres(nombres);
                            us.setApellidos(apellidos);
                            us.setTelefono(telefono);
                            us.setCorreo(correo);
                            us.setClave(clave);
                            us.setArea(area);
                            us.setRol(rol);

                            daouser.AddUsuario(us); // Se envian los datos al metodo AddUsuario
                        } else {
                            us.setMsjinfo("Las claves no coinciden");
                            request.setAttribute("info", us);
                        }

                        // Se envian los datos por parametro a los datos encapsulados en CUsuario
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.getMessage();
                    }

                    // Despues de haber agregado vuelve y lista los select de roles y areas.
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Empleado&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
                    // fin de add usuario

                    break;


                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }

            request.getRequestDispatcher("Empleado.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: En que parte pones los div o lineas en blanco? Antes del for, después del for, antes del submit? Ahora, tebhqw asegurado que realmente no están en la página? Has hecho en el explorador la opción de inspeccionar pagina y has visto si realmente el foreach no se realizo? Lo anterior es para descartar estilos que estén desplazando el contenido y ;por último,  lo que dices pasa para los dos selectos, es decir  los dos desaparecen o solo uno?;

Answer (score 0):

me llama la atención que estés llamando los items de la variable en jstl como si fuese en java, es decir rol.getId() en lugar de rol.id
Prueba ese cambio.

Saludos

Comment: Jorge Castro ya lo echo pero da error no carga la pagina si lo hago de esa manera. Estoy revisando y son los forEach no estoy seguro que puede ser por ejemplo si me carga mas de 7 datos no me muestra nada si me muestra 6 datos si me lista los datos de la db. Nose si sea el servidor TomCat o sea mejor usar con glash flish server

Comment: Con que servidor estas corriendo el sistema ??

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/191304)

Comment: Estoy usando Tomcat

Comment: Ruslan López como así ?? a qué se refiere con eso

Comment: Se refiere a que la respuesta no cumple con los requisitos de la comunidad para ser aceptada como respuesta y por esa razón puede ser cerrada. Es importante realizar el recorrido que sugiere @RuslanLópez en los enlaces para comprender de qué se trata.